# Background in div

Tags: css, css-shapes

I made an upside down triangle for the header of my website by shaping a div. Here's the CSS.

```
.triangle{
width: 0;
height: 0;
border-style: solid;
border-width: 100px 49vw 0 49vw;
margin-top:-8px;
border-color: gray transparent transparent transparent;
width:0;
height:0;
```

}

Instead of gray as the background color, I would like to insert a picture that conforms to the triangle. Does anyone have any ideas?

Thanks
Alec

Answer (score 4, accepted):

demo - http://jsfiddle.net/euppwbub/

you can use `pseudo` element `:after` and hide outer extra content with `border`

but you need to give `height` and `background-image` for `.triangle`

```css
.triangle {
  background: url(http://dummy-images.com/abstract/dummy-480x270-Rope.jpg);
  width: 100%;
  height: 100px;
  position: relative;
}
.triangle:after {
  content: '';
  border-style: solid;
  border-width: 100px 50vw 0vh 50vw;
  border-color: transparent white;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  left: 0;
  position: absolute;
}
```

```html
<div class="triangle"></div>
```

Answer (score 2):

You cant set background image if the width is 0. It will never be visible. Instead of creating a triangle and showing an image, you can show a triangle image in a normal div. I know this doesnt really answer the question, but this is the way how you do it.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of a triangle that shows the image, you could do a regular div that shows the image, and then cover up part of it with two other triangle divs pointing the other way to cover it up.

So you would have your image div and then using positioning you have a white triangle pointing up with the top point flush with the left of the div and another one positioned with the top point on the far right of the div.

Not super practical, but it achieves the effect you want.

You should probably just use an image that's already in the shape of a triangle unless you're going to be using different images from users for example that you don't have a practical way to edit by hand.